# :where with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got these associations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
   has_one :position 
end

Class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user 
end
```

And I want to get users with positions. I tried to

```
User.where(:position != nil)
```

but it doesn't work cause there is no position_id fileld in users table.

How can I get users with positions?

Comment: I found answer, the scope should look like 'scope :has_position, lambda {
    joins(:position).
    where("positions.user_id IS NOT ?", nil)
  }'

Comment: By the way `:position != nil` will never do what you want in Ruby, because that expression just evaluates to true because the symbol "position" is not equal to the ruby "nil" object.  Your code was equivalent to `Users.where(true)`.

Comment: @DavidGrayson good notice, I also read it in Rails 3 way book, and answer to question was there too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User.includes(:position).where("positions.id IS NOT NULL")

Answer (score 0):

Modify your schema.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
   belongs_to :position 
end

class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :user 
end
```

This way `users` table will contain `position_id` and you'll be able to do `User.where(:position_id => nil)`

Comment: sorry, but I need exactly associations what was written above

Comment: You need `user_id` to be in `positions` table? No problem, use another answer :-)